# Using L'hopital's rule to prove differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> **Question:** Define
>   $$
> f(x) = \left\{\begin{aligned}
> & \frac{2x\cos(x)}{x+\sin(x)}  &&: x \ne 0 \\
> &1 &&: x = 0
> \end{aligned}
> \right.$$
>
> Show $f'(0)$ exist and find the value of it.

**My Attempt:**

After applying L'Hôpital's rule once I get $$\lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{2\cos(x)-2x\sin(x)}{2x+\sin(x)+x\cos(x)}$$

I cannot continue with L'hopital's rule as it is no longer in the $\frac{0}{0}$ form.

Where am I going wrong? Thank you.

Comment: What about repeat differentiating. But actually L'Hospital rule work for differentiability functions

Comment: It seems that a factor $x$ can be cancelled from numerator and denumerator for the $x\ne 0$ term? - And as written ,$f$ is not even continuous

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't quite see where I'm going wrong, could you elaborate please?

Comment: As it is written, the f(x) is not continuous at 0.  Check that you have the problem correct.  If you do, you are done.  If not, then correct it.  Step 1.  prove continuity.  Step 2, prove differentiability.

Comment: Sorry the question was written wrong! I have now updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly by definition:

$$f'(0):=\lim,_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2\cos x-1-\frac{\sin x}x}{x+\sin x}\stackrel{\text{l'Hospital}}=$$

$$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-2\sin x-\frac{x\cos x-\sin x}{x^2}}{1+\cos x}\;\;\;\color{red}{(*)}$$

Now, observe that

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{ x\cos x-\sin x}{x^2}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-\sin x}{2}=0\implies\;\color{red}{(*)}=\frac{-0-0}2=0$$

Comment: Could you explain how you got the first equality please? What is $f(0)$? I subbed in 0 for $f(x)$ and I get 0

Comment: Where is the $1-\sin(x)$ coming from?

Comment: @THISISIT453 As follows: $$f(x)-f(0)=\frac{2x\cos x}{x+\sin x}-1=\frac{2x\cos x-x-\sin x}{x+\sin x}$$ and now divide the above by $\;x\;$ and that's all.

Comment: @THISISIT453 What $\;1-\sin x\;$ are you talking about? Where?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it as follows
\begin{align}
f'(0) &= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2x\cos x - x - \sin x}{x^{2} + x\sin x}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{2x\cos x - x - \sin x}{x^{2}\left(1 + \dfrac{\sin x}{x}\right)}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{2x\cos x - 2x + x - \sin x}{x^{2}}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x - \sin x}{x^{2}} - 2x\cdot\frac{1 - \cos x}{x^{2}}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(0 - 2\cdot 0\cdot\frac{1}{2}\right)\notag\\
&= 0\notag
\end{align}
The limit $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x - \sin x}{x^{2}} = 0$$ can be evaluated easily by Taylor series, L'Hospital, or squeeze theorem.